# Are alphabet questions off-topic?

Tags: discussion

Stack sites consider any opinion-based questions as off topic since they have no direct answer. With conlangs, there will be a lot of people creating their own alphabets who may ask questions on this site that are on the line between objective and subjective. Where should we draw the line on what's on or off topic?

For example, "How can I create letters for my conlang?" is obviously subjective, while "What is the best proportion of vowels to consonants?" can be answered through the analysis of existing languages. Things such as "What's the minimum (sensible) number of consonants I can have?" are technically answerable, if given enough context of the language itself.

Since SO sites are supposed to primarily be a reference source, and Q+A comes second, should we enforce that questions about the OP's specific conlang be off topic unless related to a more neutral concept? For example, the question "How can I make [word] fit into the theme of my language?" could be reworded as "How can I make new words that follow the same linguistic tone as my existing language?" The second question is more general, and could apply to other languages while still provoking answers of the same type. This would help reduce duplicates... I think

Comment: I keep saying this elsewhere but it bears repeating: only the off-topic close reasons are for non-topicity. Unclear, too broad and opinion-based are usually applied to questions that are generally *on*-topic.

Comment: "while "What is the best proportion of vowels to consonants?" can be answered through the analysis of existing languages." No it can't. Statistics can't make judgement calls. Any time a question asks what is "best" it nearly always should be closed with the primarily opinion based close reason. Some, but not all, of those questions can be fairly easily rewritten to ask what would be the most natural option (based on the natural languages), but that is not a goal for all conlangs.

Comment: Note that there is a fundamental difference between the phonology of a conlang (such as number of vowels and consonants) and its writing system.

Answer (score 4):

This well-received question was actually asked on worldbuilding:

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/49385/what-are-some-tips-for-designing-symbols-for-a-constructed-language

and I see no problems with a similar question on this site.